# Ajax request to show contents of my bash script echo using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to output my bash script on my webpage when I click submit on my form. Currently, I can see my script execute successfully on click, but this takes me to another page. I want it to return the output on the same page.

HTML:

```
<form action="testexec.php" method="post">
<label class="col">Up/down</label>
<span class="col">
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r1" value="1" />
  <label for="r1">Up</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r2" value="2" />
  <label for="r2">Down</label>
</span>
<span class="col">
  <input type="submit" class="button"/>
</span>
</form>
```

testexec.php:

```
 <?php
 if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

 if(isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 1)
 { $output = shell_exec("/var/www/html/testscripts/up.sh");}


 if(isset($_POST['option'])  && $_POST['option'] == 2)
 { $output = shell_exec("/var/www/html/testscripts/down.sh");}

 //header('Location: http:/mydirectory/systemTest.php?success=true');

 echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
}
?>
```

up.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /tmp/testfile
ls -ltr /tmp
echo "I am Up"
```

I'm trying to do something like the following but it isn't working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url:"testexec.php",
            type: "POST", 
            success:function(result){
            alert(result);
    }
    });
    });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `<script>` as following (and I presume you are using jQuery, based on your sample code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Removed $(document).ready(), as this is a deprecated method as of jQuery 3.0 and is not the best practice. Especially for this script, it is not needed at all - AJAX is triggered upon button press, not upon loading
        // Changed "button" to ".button" to correctly select the pressed input button
        $(".button").click(function(event){
            // Prevent the default HTML form submission from going ahead - for our purposes, this stops the page from navigating away
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:"testexec.php",
                type: "POST", 
                // Have to send the option number with the POST request - the backend is expecting a $_POST['option'] number. In AJAX, this is done with 'data'
                data: {option: $('input[type=radio]:checked').val()},
                dataType: "text",
                success:function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

More info on the above:

- Why `$(document).ready()` is deprecated and should be avoided: https://api.jquery.com/ready/
- How jQuery `.class` selectors work: https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/
- Suppressing the default behaviour with `event.preventDefault()`: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/
- Sending data together with the AJAX POST request (with the examples further down the page for more clarification): http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#data-types

Comment: I did change that, and it does seem to be outputting on my page now, however, it seems to be complaining about my testexec.php on line 15 ' echo "<pre>$output</pre>";'   Undefined variable: output in testexec.php on line 15, after i comment that line out, it just copies my while HTML page on the alert.

Comment: Of course, not :) We need to send the data for the POST request as well. Edited.

Comment: That did it! Could you kindly explain the code with comments :)

Comment: Edited again with comments and links for further exploration

Answer (score -1):

Can I suggest that you change your HTML file (named as .php, not .html) as following and not need the AJAX script. This will reload the current page and spit out the $output after the `<form>`:

```
<?php
 if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

 if(isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 1)
 { $output = shell_exec("/var/www/html/testscripts/up.sh");}


 if(isset($_POST['option'])  && $_POST['option'] == 2)
 { $output = shell_exec("/var/www/html/testscripts/down.sh");}
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<label class="col">Up/down</label>
<span class="col">
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r1" value="1" />
  <label for="r1">Up</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r2" value="2" />
  <label for="r2">Down</label>
</span>
<span class="col">
  <input type="submit" class="button"/>
</span>
</form>
<?php
     echo "<pre>" . ( ($output) ?: '' ) . "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Is there not a way to do this with Ajax?

Comment: Yeah, see the other answer.